# Laptop keyboard not working when trying to install various flavours of Ubuntu from live USB

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb, keyboard, installation

Today I have acquired a new laptop, Maibenben X565, with pre-installed Kubuntu 22.10. Kubuntu 22.10 is no longer supported, so I wasn't able to update and install packages I need, and was forced to install another version of Linux. So I downloaded Ubuntu 23.10, created a live boot USB, and tried to install it.

The keyboard works in the preinstalled Kubuntu 22.10 and in BIOS, but ceases to work once I start the installation process. The touchpad works well. I then tried to install Kubuntu 23.10, with exactly the same effect. Finally, I took the live USB I used to install Linux Mint 21.2 to my old laptop, and yes, the keyboard of the new laptop does not work there as well. Needles to say, I didn't have this problem installing Mint to my old laptop.

I googled and found out that a lot of people have had the same problem with a USB keyboard or when installing Linux on a virtual machine. For the few who had the same problem when installing to laptop with integrated keyboard, choosing a different distribution of Linux worked, or, in some cases, they were able to complete the installation process without the keyboard or with a USB keyboard and then perform some manipulations after the installation that fixed the problem. These manipulations were not described in enough detail for me to understand them.

So, how do I solve this problem (given the fact that I don't have a USB keyboard)?

Comment: Are there keyboard drivers for your keyboard?   I do not need keyboard drivers for my machine but I do not see any other cause in your case.

Comment: How do I check this?

Comment: You would need to check the manufacturer's support site.

Comment: There are some "Control Center" drivers, but it's hard to understand what they are for, and they seem to be Windows drivers

Comment: And these drivers installation process is described literally "download a folder with a bunch of stuff and run an .exe file in it"

Comment: It would be good to edit your question with some formatting - like paragraphs and so on. Like this, it's just a wall-of-text.

Comment: I have reformatted the question

Comment: Try starting over at the beginning, following https://phoenixnap.com/kb/ubuntu-22-04-lts and using an ISO from Ubuntu (I'd suggest 22.04 LTS, or 24.04 LTS when it becomes available), and Kubuntu (or Rufus from a Windows PC) to make the installation USB.

Comment: Do you mean that LTS should have better hardware compatibility?